# How to access child views of CollectionView?

Tags: xamarin.forms

There's a few cases where I would like to access the child views of `CollectionView`. Here's a few examples of why:

1. CollectionView doesn't set the `Selected` VisualState on the selected item, when the item is not a reference type (for example an enum), and the `SelectedItem` is set in code, either by setting the property, or by data binding. So in order to support the use enums in my CollectionView, I want manually set the VisualState when the selection changes.
2. CollectionView always has the height of 100% of screen height. It's not very practical in many situations, and in some cases where I know it's only a few items, I want to calculate the height of all children, and set the `HeightRequest` of my CollectionView accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I've used `StackLayout` with `BindableLayout.ItemsSource` instead of `CollectionView`. Here, I had access to the child views, and am able to set the `VisualState` of children as I please.